# How to display a popup when closing a Kivy app

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I would like to show a popup confirming the user would really like to close the application when it would normally close.

I would like to do this on an Android and Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

`app.stop()` function is actually called when exiting Kivy app.
Customized this function as much as you like:

```
class MyApp(App):

    def stop(self, *largs):
        # Open the popup you want to open and declare callback if user pressed `Yes`
        popup = ExitPopup(title="Are you sure?")
        popup.bind(on_confirm=partial(self.close_app, *largs))
        popup.open()

    def close_app(self, *largs):   
        super(MyApp, self).stop(*largs)

class ExitPopup(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExitPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_confirm')

    def on_confirm(self)
        pass

    def on_button_yes(self)
        self.dispatch('on_confirm')
```

In the kv file, bind `on_release` method of `Yes` button to the `on_button_yes` function.
If that button is presses, `on_button_yes()` would be called, hence `on_confirm` event would be dispatched, and the app will be closed.

Comment: Might consider using `app.on_stop()`