# Kivy - Confirm on application close

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to show a confirmation popup when the close button is pressed on my Windows Kivy app. I've tried overriding stop function but even though it gets called, it doesn't show the confirmation popup and the application just closes immediately. I based my solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426730/popup-on-close-app-kivy)

```
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Inst = MyInstance()
        return Inst

    def stop(self, *largs):
        print "stop called"
        popup = ConfirmationPopup()
        popup.open()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `close` button is a kivy button, you can just call you popup from there. If you are talking about the window close icon, you can catch that event as:

```
Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)
```

And call your popup from your `self.on_request_close` method. If that method returns `False`, the app will be closed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that function, however, docs state that "If a function bound to this event returns True, the window will not be closed." Only by returning False, I was able to show confirmation dialog.

Comment: Oops, you are right. Sorry about that. I have edited my answer to reflect the correct information. Thanks.